# О сочетании "в возможно короткий срок"

Tags: грамотная-речь

**В возможно короткий срок.**

Очевидно, что в данном выражении слово  ***возможно*** ― это обычное (не предикативное) наречие со значением "по возможности", но в словаре такое значение вроде бы не обозначено и подобные примеры не приводятся.

Можно предположить, что это сочетание является **устойчивой формой, принятой в деловой литературе.**

**И вопросы:**

1) Существуют ли другие  примеры подобных сочетаний для слова ***возможно***?

2) **Насколько современна и востребована такая форма**, ведь существуют другие варианты:

Например: Вопрос № 294560

Добрый день. Как правильно написать: **1) В минимально короткие сроки 2) В максимально короткие сроки?**

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Правильно: **в самые короткие сроки, в кратчайшие сроки, в минимальные сроки**.

3) Можно ли составить **другое сочетание, используя семантику** слов "возможно", "по возможности"?

**Из словаря:**

ВОЗМОЖНО. I. **нареч., в функц. сказ.** Есть, имеется возможность; допустимо, можно. В. ли с этим согласиться? Не знаю, в. ли будет с ним увидеться. Вполне в., что это произойдёт. II. вводн. сл. Может быть, вероятно. III. частица.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Существуют ли другие примеры подобных сочетаний для слова возможно?**

Словарь Ожегова даёт для слова **возможно** такое значение:

> 3. **возможно**, нареч., со сравн. ст. **Насколько можно**. *Возможно быстрее*.

Очевидно, рассматривается то же значение, хотя сравнительная степень в нём заменена другим выражением.

**2) Насколько современна и востребована такая форма, ведь существуют другие варианты**

У меня опыт использования "канцелярского" стиля невелик, и эта форма звучит для меня непривычно. Но я не исключаю, что в традициях канцелярита она имеет свою специфику использования. Мне кажется, что требования по срочности у этой формы чуть менее категоричны, чем для остальных приведенных вариантов.

**Дополнение (цитаты).**

> Нужно поставить перед собой цель — возможно больше создавать, возможно
>   быстрее работать. (А.П. Довженко)
>
> В конце концов, все мы на Земле заинтересованы, чтобы все утряслось
>   возможно быстрее. (А.П. Казанцев)

Comment: Главная задача: как возможно быстрее отправить редакционную машину. Смысл у этого предложения двойной, неудобное сочетание. А классики его использовали?

Comment: @Jasmin *как возможно быстрее* — с **как** это выражение сейчас практически не встречается. Хотя находятся цитаты прошлых веков. Пару цитат без **как** я добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что это обычное просторечие. Нормативная форма - "в насколько возможно (короткий срок)", "по возможности (в короткий срок)". Я согласен с grizzly, что тут тоже значение, что и со сравнительной степенью ("возможно быстрее"), но со сравнительной степенью никаких затруднений в понимании грамматики не возникает - и таким образом использование оправдано. А вот в нашем случае нет ни одного слова, указывающего на сравнительную или превосходную степень сочетания или чего-то подобного. Поэтому семантика **минимального** срока не очевидна. Отсюда, видимо, и ощущения неправильности. Думаю, небезосновательные.